# Index.html path cannot be hidden

Tags: css

How can I remove the index.html path when adding that file into vs code?Index.html path :

[image]

Comment: What "path"? You haven't annotated it in your screenshot.

Comment: Need more information are you talking about vs code breadcrumbs ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.